# How to build full-screen scrollview and hide nav bar without moving anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

If you look at a photo fullscreen in the iOS 7 photos app, the nav bar and toolbar fade away but the underlying scrollview isn't scaled or shifted. I've been trying to recreate the effect in Interface Builder using autolayout but every time I hide the nav bar it pulls the scrollview up.

**What I start with:**

[image]

**What happens:**

[image]

What I want to happen:

[image]

Has anyone implemented this before? It seems like no combination of autolayout constraints, scrollview insets, and automaticallyadjustscrollviewinsets is giving me what i want.

Comment: Did you set the top constraint to the top of the view, not the top layout guide?

Comment: Perfect, thank you. If you throw it down below with a link to [this][1] I'll mark it correct.

[1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html